# PHP: How to determine if var_Dump() will exceed the terminal window display?

Tags: php, xml, shell, terminal

I have a PHP script that sorts a large XML file and then spits XML contents back to the command line using var_dump(). Sometimes the XML file is very large, then you're unable to scroll up to view all of the contents.

Before printing out the contents to the terminal, I would like know if calling var_dump() on my XML array will exceed the terminal window display.

1) Is there a way to get the number of rows that will display from `var_dump($my_xml_array)`?

2) Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: var_dump is for debug output. it shouldn't be used for day-to-day "regular" output.

Comment: why don't use print_r();

Comment: You could use output buffering: http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php
ob_start
ob_get_contents
ob_clean

Comment: php somescript.php | less

Comment: If the entire output is important then why is this not being saved to a file?

Comment: `var_dump` is not fitting for XML related objects in PHP. Same applies to `print_r` or the `var_export` that is so much *"suggested"* in the answers. Ask if you'd like to learn more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [**var_export**](http://php.net/var_export) instead of `var_dump`, which allows you to store its output in a variable rather than print it using:

```
$var_out = var_export($some_var, true);

// now check & compare size of $var_out with terminal size
```

Comment: how do I check the size of `$var_out`?

Comment: Just `strlen($var_out)` would do

Answer (score 0):

two steps:

1. get the number of lines in the terminal using an exec() call to
   `tput lines`
2. get the size of your var_dump by using var_export() as anubhava mentions.

put these two together and proceed.

```
<?php

/** 
 * get lines of terminal
 */
exec("tput lines", $exec_return);
$number_of_terminal_lines = $exec_return[0];

/** 
 * get lines of var dump
 */

$test_array = array("foo"=>"bar", "baz"=>"quux");

$test_array_var_dump_string = var_export($test_array,true);

$test_array_var_dump_string_lines = substr_count( $test_array_var_dump_string, "\n" );

print "number of lines in terminal $number_of_terminal_lines\n";
print "number of lines in var dump $test_array_var_dump_string_lines\n";
```

hope this does the trick!